# BoxCoxTrans к данным имеющие разные факторы

Tags: r

Нужно применить функцию нормализации к данным по успеваемости студентов. Успеваемость дана в баллах, которые они набирают в течение семестра. Я выбрала функцию

`Transfy = BoxCoxTrans(q$баллы.по.учебе)# создали правило нормализации целевой переменной
q$y = predict(Transfy, q$баллы.по.учебе)#занормализовали`

Все хорошо, работает. Но нужно провести нормализацию в рамках каждой группы студентов, поскольку в рамках каждой группы свой максимальный балл ( то есть значение 250 в группе 1 может означать успеваемость на 50%, а в группе 2 значение 250 - 100%). То есть в другом столбце q$группа содержится информация о принадлежности к группе. Где это нужно указать?

Comment: Вам нужно думать в сторону функции `by()` в базовом R или в сторону `group_by() %>% summarize()` в пакете `dplyr`

Comment: Нашла два способа:                                                                                                        
 1)ddply(q, c("баллы.по.учебе","группа"), transform)

tapply(q$scale, list(q$`баллы по учебе`,q$группа), scale)

2)
library(dplyr)
q_scaled <- q %>% group_by(группа) %>% mutate(ycheba = scale(q$`баллы по учебе`))                     Но они тоже не работают

Comment: Без какой-то внятной структуры данных трудно отвечать: исправьте свой вопрос, приведя пример фрагмента данных, и результат, который Вы ожидаете